# Easy way to find the number of roots of a function

Tags: functions, roots

I want to know if there is an easy way to find the number of roots in a function. For example let's consider the function:

$\\f(x) = \sqrt{25-x^2}-e^{|x|}$

How many solutions does the $f(x) = 0$  equation have?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to have some intuition about the shapes of the functions. The first half of your function is a circle, and the last half is something that sort of looks like a parabola. You then consider how many ways that pseudo-parabola can intersect with the circle. In this case, it should be two.

Comment: what if there was another term for example $...+\frac{1}{x}$ then you wouldn't know anything about the shape.

Comment: You look at what function dominates and where. For instance, $x^3+\frac1x$ looks more like $x^3$ the farther you go from zero and more like $\frac1x$ the closer you get to zero. The actual function should look like two parabolas, one in Quadrant I and one in Quadrant III.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use a root finding algorithm or find some way to solve it with algebra.